# How can I change multiple word files' attribute as 'Read Only Recommended'

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I have a daily word which I need to change around 100 word files as 'read-only-recommended' before sending to client.

I cannot figure out a VBA solution to do that, could you give me a hint? Thanks and regards.

Comment: Maybe using the [ReadOnlyRecommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.readonlyrecommended) property?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Microsoft Community Answers Forum article entitled [Batch Editing MS Word Documents](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/batch-editing-ms-word-documents-file-handling/fe2ddc73-fe11-4200-bc58-cdc67c9ce915) that you should read. It provides VBA code for both Windows and Mac versions of Office. In the article's supplied code, there are two locations marked with:

> This is where you will insert your code for applying the edits you
>   want to perform

You would insert:

```
ActiveDocument.ReadOnlyRecommended = True
```